# PHP - Get difference between two datetime in seconds

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have a datetime value I want the difference between that datetime and datetime now .. I tried to convert it to timestamp and calculate the difference but I got a negative value. How to get the difference in seconds ?

```
<?php 
$datetimenow = strtotime(date("Y/m/d H:i:s"));
$mydatetime = strtotime(date('2015/10/09 14:20:00'));
echo ($datetimenow - $mydatetime);
?>
```

Comment: Make sure the later date is the first date. Or use `abs()` to ignore the negative value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead, i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Lisbon' ); //set your desired timezone
$now = new DateTime( 'NOW' );
$future = new DateTime( '2015/10/09 15:20:00' );
$diffSeconds = $future->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();
# 2220
```

Comment: ... or `Datetime::diff()->format()` : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php ... but you get an upvote anyway for using `DateTime` ;)

Comment: @CD001 that option doesn't provide more than 59 seconds. But I had the same thought initially.

Comment: @PedroLobito Thank you for your answer, I tried two different dates first (2015/10/09 17:40:44) and the second (2015/10/09 14:20:13) .. first one gives me negative value (-4478)  .. the second gives me positive value (7572) !

Answer (score 1):

I love the Carbon library... https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

```
$diff = Carbon::now()->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse('2015/10/09 14:20:00'));
```